# Disable Admin Bar Render on Plugin Page

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, admin-bar

In the WP Admin panel, I have a plugin that does certain calculations based on input from a form. I need it to print pretty, so I am attempting to render the plugin page without the admin menu etc.

I thought that `remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 10000 );` would accomplish this, but it seems to not be working as it still renders the admin panel, and not just a blank white page.

Here's what I have:

```
public function cpui_setup()
{
    add_submenu_page( NULL, __( 'WooCommerce Print Order Recipe', 'woocommerce' ),  __( 'Print Recipe', 'woocommerce' ) , 'manage_woocommerce', 'cpui_print_recipe', array( $this, 'print_recipe_page' ) );
}

public function print_recipe_page()
{
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
    require_once( 'admin/print_recipe.php' );
}
...
```

What am I overlooking?

Comment: You can inspire here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/115202/completely-remove-wp-admin-bar-for-specific-user-roles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In modern WordPress toolbar is considered *mandatory* part of admin. That is WordPress is explicitly opinionated about not letting you to disable it. While you still can kind of hack it out, it's unnecessary struggle.

If you need a blank page there is no reason to struggle with blanking admin interface for it. You could simply use `wp-admin/admin-post.php` to handle your form. Ajax endpoint would work just as well, or maybe even custom "pretty" URL endpoint.

Comment: This answer seems to be correct: All other solutions don't seem to work, and the only way to "hide" the admin bar seems to be with CSS. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0):

If you will disable the admin bar for all users on this page, use this

```
wp_deregister_script( 'admin-bar' );
        wp_deregister_style( 'admin-bar' );
        remove_action( 'init', '_wp_admin_bar_init' );  
    remove_action( 'wp_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );  
    remove_action( 'admin_footer', 'wp_admin_bar_render', 1000 );
```

in a function, where you check for your plugin page, like with `get_current_sreen()`. The [codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen) have all information and examples.

Comment: `show_admin_bar()` no longer allows to disable toolbar in admin, WP will just ignore it.

Comment: You have right, update the answer. Also it is a wrong goal in my eyes, to remove the admin bar only on one page.